# Typescript: why spread is not safe?

Tags: typescript

This is is very irretating and often case in typescript, why spread operator not safe:

```
type M = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

declare const m: M

const m2: M = {
  ...m, 
  ...{x : 1} // this thing can be anything, without error
}
```

Can anyone explain what prevents TS from considering this an error?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing) about TypeScript being a *structurally typed* language:

> ```ts
> let o = { x: "hi", extra: 1 }; // ok
> let o2: { x: string } = o; // ok
> ```
>
> Here, the object literal `{ x: "hi", extra: 1 }` has a matching literal type `{ x: string, extra: number }`. That type is assignable to `{ x: string }` since it has all the required properties and those properties have assignable types. The extra property doesn’t prevent assignment, it just makes it a subtype of `{ x: string }`.